# Changing namespace in C# VS2008 project

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008

I am re-using another C# project and building upon it. The namespace is in the form of three words separated my periods, like company.embedded.sample. I can select one of the words and use F2 to change it but I cannot delete any of the words or highlight and change the entire namespace to something like MyDemo.

Any suggestions?

Comment: you are "re-using"?  what does that mean?  If you have the source you can do whatever you want with it...  I am assuming you only have the assembly?

Comment: You cannot change a namespace of a compiled assembly. At most you can create an alias. What exactly are you trying to do?